# Writing groovy contract for spring cloud contract testing

Tags: groovy, contract, spring-cloud-contract

I am new to contract testing and want to write a groovy contract for a response which contains sub objects with strings list of dictionaries and so on.
I have a response like this:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "categories": [
          {
            "categories": [],
            "oid": "abc",
            "type": "xyz"
          },
          {
            "categories": [],
            "oid": "abb",
            "type": "xyy"
          }
        ],
        "oid": "ab"
      }
    ],
    "meta": {
      "datatype": "text",
      "language": "x",
      "market": "qw",
      "provider": "AFP",
      "status": "ok",
      "statusInfo": {},
      "supportedLanguages": [
        "x"
      ]
    }
  }
```

and for that I have written the following contract:

```
Contract.make {
    request {
        method 'GET'
        url '/foo'
    }
    response {
        status 200
        body(
                 "data"  : [
                     (
                        "categories": [
                            (
                            "categories" : [],
                            "oid" : anyNonEmptyString(),
                            "type" : "xyz"
                            ),
                            (
                            "categories" : [],
                            "oid" : anyNonEmptyString(),
                            "type" : "xyy"
                            )
                        ]
                        "oid" : regex('\w')
                     )
                 ],
                 "meta" : (
                    "datatype": "text",
                    "language": "x",
                    "market": "qw",
                    "provider": "AFP",
                    "status": "ok",
                    "statusInfo": (),
                    "supportedLanguages": ["x"]
                 )
        )
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
}
```

But is not working properly.
Can you help me to know what I am doing wrong over here.

Comment: Can you elaborate what "is not working properly" means? For sure `meta` and `categories` should have a `[]` instead of `()` braces

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak, as you see in the json response, the categories is a list of dictionaries and meta is dictionary so is it write to use [ ] instead of ( ) in groovy and the main problem is when I run the tests the contract is not picking up and stubs are not generated for this but stubs are generated for other contract.

Comment: You don't create maps like that http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Maps

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak Can you please modify my contract based on the json response so that I will understand what is wrong in my groovy contract.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/marcingrzejszczak/e0c5dc982cceacfce02e6a1289b2c891

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak Thanks for your help.
I have another question related to the contract testing:
Can we produce multiple mocks for a single contract?
Suppose we are writing contract for weather app which has url -> /getWeather
and it will produce three mocks which will have responses for sunny, rainy and snow weather.

Comment: I've added an answer to the question. Can you please mark this question as answered? RE: multiple answers for the same contract please read this section of the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-stateful-contracts

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak but in this case we have to write different contacts for each state.
Can we write one contract and produce different stubs from it?

Comment: No, you cannot do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contract is invalid. You're using parentheses where you should be using brackets

```
Contract.make {
    request {
        method 'GET'
        url '/foo'
    }
    response {
        status 200
        body(
                 "data"  : [
                     (
                        "categories": [
                            [ // was (
                            "categories" : [],
                            "oid" : anyNonEmptyString(),
                            "type" : "xyz"
                            ], // was )
                            [ // was (
                            "categories" : [],
                            "oid" : anyNonEmptyString(),
                            "type" : "xyy"
                            ] // was )
                        ]
                        "oid" : regex('\w')
                     )
                 ],
                 "meta" : [ // was (
                    "datatype": "text",
                    "language": "x",
                    "market": "qw",
                    "provider": "AFP",
                    "status": "ok",
                    "statusInfo": [:], // was ()
                    "supportedLanguages": ["x"]
                 ] // was )
        )
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
}
```